# Assets (images) in Firebase Hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-hosting

I'm implementing a web app in angular/ionic/firebase. I have an assets folder containing many icons and images (about 4 mb). Using firebase hosting, the whole folder is
downloaded every time a user connects to the site or only when a page containing a specific image is loaded? I would not like to have high data transfer costs due to the fact that all the images are always transferred

Comment: Worthwhile examining the network tab on page load. You should see a http request to domain/your-image.jpg etc. In other words, no. For proper lazy loading behaviour use https://angular.io/guide/image-directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic by default uses lazy load routing, so **images are downloaded only when the page is showed**.

If you want to make sure, it is very easy to check, only open devtools, go to "Network" panel, reload the page and there you have everything is loaded at the beginning.

Then, you can also open a page with some images and check in devtools that those images are downloaded at that moment.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Perfect, from devtools, navigating through the pages, I noticed that they are loaded on a page-by-page basis. Thank you  =)